# SP2016 crawled properties are not auto-generated in my documents set

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-search

I have an on-premise SP2016 site collection where I'm a site collection administrator.

I've created a custom Library, based on a custom Content Type inheriting from the native Document Set. I've bound that content type to my library and removed the default "Document" cotent type.

My custom Content Type contains two custom Site Columns : 
- My_Collaborator - type : Person
- My_Type - type : managed metadata (the term store is the term store of another site collection, which I've shared with this site collection)

I've had no problem adding a document in the document set, and no problem **setting a value for all the fields**, even the custom fields. I've made sure the document is **not extracted** and has a **major version**.

Then I've run a **full crawl** of the web app (I've access to that too), and made sure it was over.

Now I'm facing this problem : SharePoint doesn't seem to create a **Crawled Property** for any of my columns. I don't see them when I go to Site Settings --> **Search Schema**  (I'm not confusing with just "Schema").

**Why?** Is there a setting somehwere that would tell SharePoint to ignore that column?

There were errors in the **Crawl Log** about this specific Document Set. I didn't want to leave any potential solution out so I Reset the crawl Index ("**Reset Index**") and ran a **Full Crawl** again.
This time my document set appears as crawled and the results appear in the search results on the site.

...and yet the Crawled properties based on my columns still don't appear in the Search Schema! I'm going mad.

Comment: How are the columns and content types provisioned ?

Comment: thanks for asking, but unfortunately I've moved on and the site (which was under development) went through many changes (and several backup/restore) I've recreated some columns and so on. So I don't remember exactly how things were provisionned and what resolved the issue. It eventually sorted itself out, after some cheer luck.